# Rigid body simulation (separate by group of start time falling)

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collections, rigidbody

I'm doing animation via rigid body simulation (falling objects)
So I need one group of objects to start falling at frame 0, the second at 100, and another one at 200.

It's need to separate objects of collection and off/on on frame of animation?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use Deactivation:

[image]

You can keyframe the Deactivation box on at 0 and off at some other frame, and enable Start Deactivated, and the rigid body won't do anything until Deactivation turns off or until another rigid body collides with it.

Another way is to use a breakable constraint:

[image]

Here, the rigid body is anchored to another, animated rigid body (that might not be something which we render, might not be something which ever collides with anything) by a breakable "fixed" type constraint, with the threshold set very low.  Now, the rigid body will remain fixed in space until it fails to meet the conditions of its constraint, by presumably 0.1 Blender units here.  We can simply grab the anchor and move it more than 0.1 units over a single frame-- probably with keyframed location-- to break the constraint and let the anchored body fall.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to put them in separate collections to do that. But it could make sense to do it because then you could easier select them.

Comment: Well, how then?